# .NET & Excel Interop: Copying User Selection to Clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

Fairly straightforward scenario, for which I can't seem to find an answer *anywhere*:

- I am using a Microsoft WebBrowser
  ActiveX control (AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser) in a Windows Forms
  application.
- The WebBrowser control
  is used to display Excel workbooks in
  the application.
- I can obtain a
  reference to the internal document as
  a
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.
- What I cannot seem to find, despite
  hours of searching the Web, is any
  reliable guidance on how to determine
  the range of cells currently selected
  *by the end-user*.

Here's the problem. Since the sheet is displayed in the browser, it doesn't have the Excel toolbar displayed, and I'd like to provide at least *some* rudimentary functionality (cut, copy, paste, undo, redo, bold, italic, underscore, left, right, center, and so on) from my application's main window. In order to do that, I need to be able to forward those commands onto the active sheet. Some of those commands require knowledge of the currently selected range if I want to properly execute them.

If anyone knows how to do this, I would be forever in your debt. (Well, maybe not forever, but you get the point.)

[NOTE: I use the old ActiveX control so that I can trap the NavigateComplete2 event to capture the reference to the internal document. The .NET WebBrowser control doesn't expose this functionality the same way.]

Comment: Even though the toolbar isn't present, could you not do the regular things (bold, italic, cut, copy, paste) with keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Sure, *I* could. But this is designed for end-users. I want the available functionality to be *obvious* to them. Keyboard shortcuts are not obvious to The Average User(TM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the workbook reference, you should be able to do .Application.Selection to get the current selected Range.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) includes an Excel compatible Windows Forms control which you might find easier to use in your .NET applications.

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: Alas, I've seen your component, and it's price. It's WAY out of my price range. :(

Answer (score 0):

Check using the following code....

```
if (wkbk.Application.Selection != null)
{
   if (wkbk.Application.Selection is Excel.Range)
   {
      //your code to obtain an Excel.range object goes here...
   }
}
```